# Kratos serve can't find the configuration file

Tags: docker, configuration

## Setup

As per [Ory Kratos Docker Documentation](https://www.ory.sh/kratos/docs/install#docker) I run:

```
$ docker pull oryd/kratos:v0.7.1-alpha.1
$ docker run --rm -it oryd/kratos version
Version:            v0.7.1-alpha.1
Build Commit:   4fe76af1302d45ddf4cf3c2c5949311c9cf1f8b8
Build Timestamp:    2021-07-22T17:41:40Z
```

### Running the image in a container

What happens here is that no configuration file is specified, so it just errors out the keys that are required.

```
$ docker run oryd/kratos:v0.7.1-alpha.1

The configuration contains values or keys which are invalid:
identity: <nil>
          ^-- one or more required properties are missing

The configuration contains values or keys which are invalid:
selfservice.default_browser_return_url: <nil>
                                        ^-- one or more required properties are missing

The configuration contains values or keys which are invalid:
courier.smtp.connection_uri: <nil>
                             ^-- one or more required properties are missing

time=2021-07-27T17:46:47Z level=fatal msg=Unable to instantiate configuration....
```

## Issue

When using the Docker Images, Kratos does not recognize a configuration file with the --config flag.

Since containers are ran independently, I figured I'd have to use a file on the Daemon while running the serve command from the daemon and it seems Ory Kratos has a section for this also at [Ory Kratos Docker Image](https://www.ory.sh/kratos/docs/guides/docker/#creating-custom-docker-image))

```
docker run --rm -it oryd/kratos serve --config /home/ory/kratos.yml

FATA[2021-07-27T18:35:41Z] Unable to instantiate configuration.          audience=application error=map[message:open /home/ory/kratos.yml: no such file or directory] service_name=Ory Kratos service_version=v0.7.1-alpha.1
```

Relevant Files:

The [configuration](https://github.com/ory/kratos/blob/master/contrib/quickstart/kratos/email-password/kratos.yml)

Answer (score 2):

> message:open /home/ory/kratos.yml: no such file or directory

You error above means the container can't find `/home/ory/kratos.yml`.

> I figured I'd have to use a file on the Daemon

If I catch you correctly, you mean you put `kratos.yml` in the rootfs of docker host, but you did not put it inside container, this makes your container can't find the configuration file.

So, here you need to mount the file in host into container, something like next:

```
docker run --rm -v /home/ory/kratos.yml:/home/ory/kratos.yml -it oryd/kratos serve --config /home/ory/kratos.yml
```

You need to use the correct path of `kratos.yml` on host of course.

Detail refers to [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only).

Comment: Were you able to successfully run the docker command?  Could you show me your output after building the image and running it in detached mode?

Comment: Is there a way to mount this file from host to the container inside of the Dockerfile?

Comment: I don't know `kratos`. But with the configure file you attached, I use next command to launch the container: `docker run --rm -v `pwd`/kratos.yml:/home/ory/kratos.yml -it oryd/kratos serve --config /home/ory/kratos.yml`, it will then not print `no such file or directory`, though it will output other something like `Unable to connect to database, retrying.`, but I think this is nolonger a docker issue, just how you correctly use `kratos`. Maybe in your environment everything is ok.

Comment: To copy file in `Dockerfile`, you could add next in your Dockerfile: `COPY kratos.yml /home/ory/kratos.yml`.